# How does one dispose of broken mayim achronim cups?

Tags: disposal, mayim-acharonim

How do you dispose of broken mayim achronim cups?  Mine was plastic and it fell and broke and cannot be fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: The trash or recycling are good options depending on the type of plastic

Comment: If your cup does in fact have God's name on it, feel free to re-add the tag I removed. Also, can you clarify if you are asking about halacha (and if so you can [edit] to add the halacha tag as well)?

Answer (score 2):

Items once used for a mitzvah (tashmishei mitzvah) that wore out do not require genizah, according to the letter of the law. 
Mishnah Berurah 21:1
(א) חוטי ציצית וכו' - וה"ה לכל תשמישי מצוה כגון סוכה ולולב ושופר וכל כה"ג לאחר שנתבטלו ואינם עומדין עוד למצותן:

But it is still good to put them in genizah, and not just chuck them straight in the garbage, according to the Rema ad loc. This is a way of showing respect.

There is a Halachic disagreement whether mayim achronim is considered a mitzvah nowadays, so that is an extra reason to be lenient, even for Ashkenazim.

A practical solution would be to wrap it up carefully before placing in the garbage container, assuming it is not practical to place it with the Sheimos.

Comment: "it is still good to put them in genizah" assuming they're actually tashmishei mitzvah which is not obvious.

Comment: You correctly say that _Rama_ says it's good to put _tashmishe mitzva_ in _g'niza_. You then note that this is Ashkenazic practice; that's not my experience. I wonder whether you can cite some evidence of it. As far as I know, people (who aren't using them) discard their four _minim_ after _Sukos_, for example. In a respectful way, to be sure, as outlined in the _Rama_, but discard them nonetheless.

Comment: I don't think I ever heard of people putting their *netilat yadayim* cups in *geniza* (to take a more common example). Nor did I ever read one should do so. Is it common in your community? (I am asking seriously)

Comment: In Jerusalem, where I live, Ashkenazim are careful not to dispose of old mitzvah objects by just chucking them in the garbage. This is in accordance with the ruling of the Rema. Whether a mayim achronim cup is a mitzvah object is debatable, as I mentioned in my answer, but those who wash mayim achronim usually consider it to be a mitzvah, perhaps even one with Kabbalistic significance. Nevertheless, I will edit my answer...